# How to remove integration in gitlab.com for a project

Tags: gitlab, webhooks

I am trying to remove a integration by webhook to discord in gitlab.com for a particular project `Settings -> Integrations -> Discord Notifications`

My user have role Owner inherited from the project group of that project.

Seems that this option is existing for a project group, when I visit `Settings -> Integrations -> Discord Notification` in a form of `Reset` button, but I can't find this for a project.

Thanks,
Radek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable a project integration that's a normal webhook, you will need to be a maintainer on the project, and then go to `Settings > Webhooks`, scroll to the bottom, and press delete.

To disable one of the built-in integrations from the "Integrations" section, you can simple disable the `Active` checkbox at the top of the page

Comment: Patrick, I edited the question to be more precise - exactly I meant Integrations settings screen for Discord Notifications, sorry for confuson.

Comment: If you want to remove a webhook integration from the "integrations" section, just uncheck the "Active" checkbox on the top.

Comment: Wow, thanks, that was so indistinctive that I overlook it completly! If you update your answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done - I added it to the first answer so that folks know to check both areas if they find it in the future.